# Slim 6ft high evergreen hedge for a UK garden?

Tags: plant-recommendations, hedge

I'm interested in surrounding my UK front garden with a evergreen hedge border.

- The garden is small, enough for 2 small family cars.
- So is it possible to grow a "slim" evergreen hedge which is at least 6ft high?

Comment: Such plants exist, but it is hard to recommend without knowing where you live. Also, are you looking for an evergreen or deciduous plant?

Comment: @oshirowanen Where in the UK ie Which County or North, Central, South, East, West in the UK.

Comment: @oshirowanen Also, unless UK law has changed (in the past 5 years) or you live in a home (town, etc) with an exemption, 6ft (1.8m) is the maximum fence/hedge height a homeowner can put around their property (boundary/line)...

Answer (score 6):

[Yews should do the job](http://www.ashridgetrees.co.uk/Yew-English-Taxus-baccata) as they can be trimmed easily and sprout new growth on old wood.  They are slow growing unless you pamper them with water and fertilizer the first few years.

Even easier, and thinner, is a wood/aluminium/steel fence with vines growing on it. You can get privacy, flower and fruit with less than three feet of width.  Some vines that would work are roses, clematis, wisteria.

Comment: A fence with vines would also be stronger. A thin hedge is going to be vulnerable to physical damage - weather, cars, etc.

Comment: +1 Good call on the fence. Just make sure the fence is sturdy enough to hold up whatever you plan to grow up it. Some vines are vigorous enough to pull fences apart.