# Which Indian/ Asian Bamboo species grow to 1.5"-2" inch diameter have thick segment wall & high lateral strength?

Tags: plant-recommendations

Which Indian/ Asian Bamboo species grow to 1.5"-2" inch diameter have thicker segment wall & high lateral strength?

> Before you down vote & vote to close, please note similar questions
>   that are valid:
>
> [Slim 6ft high evergreen hedge for a UK garden?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2070/slim-6ft-high-evergreen-hedge-for-a-uk-garden?rq=1)
>
> [Which are some good indoor plants for upside down planting?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5246/which-are-some-good-indoor-plants-for-upside-down-planting?rq=1)
>
> [What climbing vines will cover a 40' high cliff in southern Spain?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5764/what-climbing-vines-will-cover-a-40-high-cliff-in-southern-spain?rq=1)
>
> [What bamboo species for a container-bound green wall?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/7780/what-bamboo-species-for-a-container-bound-green-wall?rq=1)

There are various bamboo varieties across the region. So far, we have been unable to get clarity on this from various on line sources & books. We are trying to approach some groups locally who might have more knowledge and will post back once we have more info.

- We are thinking of having them as **naturally growing separators / walls/ fences**, as well as use them in various ways for **landscaping**.

  - Strength & higher ability to withstand high winds & monsoon is a good point as well
  - Additional pro of keeping out small creatures without building & maintaining wooden fences
- Maybe a bunch of them can hold up a hammock and/ or some other visually different landscaping ideas :)  e.g. A friend of mine does Vertical Gardens, so maybe add some of that to the mix.

  - I can post a link about vertical gardens if needed. But, this is more long term idea when they've grown & are strong enough

### We'd like Indian Bamboo that is laterally strong & stiff at the 1.5-2" diameter i.e. Bamboo with a "thicker segment wall"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'lateral strength', can you clarify please?

Comment: This is really the wrong community for this question. This question is about structural engineering rather than about gardening. Though I will admit there is some crossover since it is a plant selection, however you need an engineer who has those figures to answer the question. Maybe a moderator can move this question to the engineering community?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is really a structural engineering question rather than a gardening or landscaping question.

Comment: @Escoce - we don't really know that, although it is a fair assumption. But the question might mean the asker wants to know which bamboo is less likely to break in high winds, despite having thinner stems. There's just not enough info in the question really.

Comment: @Bamboo that may be true, but an engineer with experience in renewable resources would be the best person to ask this question. They are the ones that would have this figure.

Comment: @ Escoce Agree - if the question is regarding strength for construction purposes, which we still don't know....

Comment: 1. Which engineering forum are you suggesting? 2. I dont think any people or engineers I know of ANYWHERE know much about Bamboos or species of Bamboos. We have gardens where we wish to grow Bamboo - We'd like to chose such a variety - Let me update the question with more info. PS: We do not want super thick bamboos

Comment: @AlexS hi there, then please explain what your purpose is. It will help a lot.

Comment: @Escoce - We'd like Indian Bamboo that is laterally strong & stiff at the 1.5-2" diameter?

Comment: Then you want a bamboo that grows to 1.5-2 inches with a thicker segment wall. I don't have that answer but it may help those who know those characteristics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about gardening

Comment: @kevinsky - It is, about landscaping part of gardening and we'd like to pick the right bamboo for this. We do not have enough information about it  and have been unable to ascertain from sources online so far. I have reached to some friends who might connect me a group who knows bamboo species better.

Comment: @kevinsky - http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2070/slim-6ft-high-evergreen-hedge-for-a-uk-garden?rq=1  

http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5246/which-are-some-good-indoor-plants-for-upside-down-planting?rq=1 

http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5764/what-climbing-vines-will-cover-a-40-high-cliff-in-southern-spain?rq=1

http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/7780/what-bamboo-species-for-a-container-bound-green-wall?rq=1

Comment: If we assume that you want to grow this bamboo, your question is a plant-rec, entirely on topic.

Comment: @J.Musser - Yes. That's why I am asking in Gardening, not in wood working. I asked my friend who does vertical gardens, and he likes the idea, but does not know enough about Bamboo.